# How to compare and replace individual cell values in data according to a list?: Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing numerical values. I want to replace all values in the dataframe by comparing individual cell values to the respective elements of the list. The length of the list and the length of the columns are the same. Here's an example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
Output
   a  b  c
0  101  2  3
1  4  500  6
2  712  8  9


list_numbers = [100,100,100]
```

I want to compare individual cell values to the respective elements of the list.
So, the column 'a' will be compared to 100. If the values are greater than hundred, I want to replace the values with another number.
Here is my code so far:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df_columns = df.columns
df_index = df.index

#Creating a new dataframe to store the values. 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index= df_index, columns = df_columns)
df1 = df1.fillna(0)

for index, value in enumerate(df.columns):
    #df.where replaces values where the condition is false
    df1[[value]] = df[[value]].where(df[[value]] > list_numbers [index], -1)
    df1[[value]] = df[[value]].where(df[[value]] < list_numbers [index], 1)

#I am getting something like: nan for column a and error for other columns. 

#The output should look something like:
Output
   a  b  c
0  1  -1  -1
1 -1   1  -1
2  1  -1  -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating over a DataFrame iterates over its column names. So you could simply do:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for i, c in enumerate(df):
    df1[c] = np.where(df[c] >= list_numbers[i], 1, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid iterating over the columns, and use `numpy` broadcasting (which is more efficient):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.where(df.values > np.array(list_numbers), 1, -1),
    columns=df.columns)

df1
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1 -1 -1
1 -1  1 -1
2  1 -1 -1
```